# Assign to a string literal an array

Tags: c

It is undefined behavior to do this?

```
char *a = "hello";
char b[] = "abcd";
a = b;
```

My compiler throws no warning, with the maximum warning level.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no UB here. You are simply re-assigning a pointer to point at the address of the start of the array instead.

Note that you are not actually modifying the value that `a` is pointing at, only `a` itself, and `a` is a normal `char *`.

Comment: What happen with "hello" is lost?

Comment: @cheroky, If you had allocated that memory, it would be a memory leak because you could never free it. However, since it is a string literal whose memory was allocated by the compiler (likely in a read-only region), you could never free it anyways, so not having a pointer to it is irrelevant.